# Calculating the integral expression $\int_0^{\infty}\lambda^{t-1}e^{-\lambda z}d\lambda$ for complex-valued z

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

The problem is computing the integral expression
$$f(t)=\int_0^{\infty}\lambda^{t-1}e^{-\lambda z}d\lambda$$
where z is a complex variable with $Re(z)> 0$ and t is a real variable.
Is it correct to substitute $w=\lambda z$ in the integral and write down $f(t)$ as
$$f(t)=z^{-t}\int_0^{\infty}w^{t-1}e^{-w}dw=z^{-t}\Gamma(t)$$
where w is a complex variable?

Note that while in the first integral $\lambda$ is a real variable which approaches positive infinity of real numbers, in the second integral $w$ is a complex variable and the integral is only meaningful when its value is independent from how $w$ approaches the infinity point of the extended complex plane.

Comment: No. What is $z^{-t}$ when $z$ is complex and $t$ is not an integer?

Comment: @Did that's not a problem, because $\Re(z) \ge 0$, so we can take the standard branch of $\log(z)$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I know, but I am not sure the OP realizes this (for example, the condition $\Re(z)\geqslant0$ should read $\Re(z)\gt0$).

Comment: @Did Yes, I was just about to make the edit.

Comment: @Did Oh, you must have commented before the OP edited in $\text{Re}(z) > 0$.  That is why I didn't appreciate you were trying to correct the OP.

Comment: @Did, but now I see the OP hasn't made the edit!

Answer (score 1):

If you can persuade yourself that the integral exists, and that it has to be analytic in $z$ for $\Re(z) > 0$, then you can argue that you have two analytic functions that agree on the positive real axis.  Hence they must agree on $\Re(z) > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the finite integral from $0$ to $\Lambda$ instead. When you do the substitution $w = \lambda z$ with $dw = z d\lambda$ the limits of integration become $0$ and $\Lambda/z$, so in fact your new integral actually has a very specific contour - the half-line from the origin to infinity along the complex number $1/z$.